# SDWebImage issues: Cocoa error 513 and Unrecognized selector send to instance

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, sdwebimage

I have implemented the `SDWebImage` exactly as the description ([link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)) said using xcode 5, and it gives me no errors. This is what the piece of code looks like:

```
CustomCell *customcell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(currentIndexPath) inSection:0]];
    Model *model = self.products[currentIndexPath];
    NSString *productImageNumber = model.productImageNumber;
    NSString *imageUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.imagine-app.nl/ProductImages/%@%@",productImageNumber,@".jpg"];
    [customcell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-square.jpg"]];
```

But when I run the app, and I press the button that uses the `SDWebImage`, I get two errors:

```
!!!!! Error creating directory /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Photos/Process: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.) !!!!
```

and

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1752ea90
```

I can't figure out where they come from and neither how to solve them because, as mentioned, Xcode gives me no error or issue when I'm editing my code.

I'm a beginner so I may be missing out something simple, bus as mentioned, It is not the implementation of the `SDWebImage` that causes this, because I checked it numerous times and everything appeared to be right.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this? thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try to add exception breakpoint and see on which line the app crashes.

Comment: I did! everything works just fine. as soon as it gets to the setImageWithUrl:placeHolderImage it crashes.

Comment: Have you imported the UIImageView+WebCache.h header? Also check if the imageView property of the cell is really there and valid.

Comment: yes I have implemented them. strange thing about that is, the documentation (see link in question) tells me to do it like this: `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`, but I have to do it like this: 
`#import "SDWebImage.framework/Headers/UIImageView+WebCache.h"`. that makes sense to me because that is the 'way to come there', but maybe it shouldn't be like this? The image view is also there and valid. it's a UIImageView I placed in a customCell.

Comment: Does your CustomCell have imageView property?

Comment: yes it does. sorry for the late response. All these little things actually seem to be correct. maybe it is the fact that I can't implement the header as supposed to??

Comment: @verbumdei sorry forgot to tag

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32563/discussion-between-verbumdei-and-imagine-digital)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the SDWebImage .m files are not added in the target membership. Try to add those files under *Build Phases* > *Compile Sources*.

If you are also adding the MKAnnotationView+WebCache files, you need to include MapKit.framework under *Link Binary With Libraries* section.